# Redux-saga is stuck on yield call

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I try to run the next code on node 6.2.1. It logs **1, 2,** and then stuck. I cannot undestand why it doesn't continue execution to the line yield take('TEST')... Seems that anotherSaga finishes and logs 2 but control isn't returned to rootSaga. Can anyone help me please?

```
const {runSaga, delay} = require('redux-saga');
const {take, put, call} = require('redux-saga/effects');

function* anotherSaga() {
  yield call(delay, 1000);
  console.log(2);
}

function* rootSaga() {
  while(true) {
    console.log(1);
    yield call(anotherSaga);
    console.log(3);
    const action = yield take('TEST');
    console.log(4);
    yield put(action);
  }
}

runSaga(
  rootSaga(),
  {
    subscribe(callback) {
      return setInterval(() => (callback({type: 'TEST'})), 1000);
    },
    dispatch(action) {
      console.log(action);
    },
    getState() {}
  }
);
```

**Update**: but code without runSaga works as expected logging 1,2,3,4

```
const {createStore, applyMiddleware} = require('redux');
const createSagaMiddleware = require('redux-saga').default;
const {delay} = require('redux-saga');
const {take, put, call} = require('redux-saga/effects');

function* anotherSaga() {
  yield call(delay, 2000);
  console.log(2);
}

function* rootSaga() {
  while(true) {
    console.log(1);
    yield call(anotherSaga);
    console.log(3);
    const action = yield take('TEST');
    console.log(4);
    yield put(action);
    console.log('---')
  }
}

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (state === undefined) {
    return {};
  }

  return state;
}

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

setInterval(() => (store.dispatch({type: 'TEST'})), 1000);
```

Comment: Did you try this code without runSaga?

Comment: @kuy I've tried and it works as expected. Please look the code in main topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is due to the `subscribe` function not returning the correct value. Above it's returning the result of `setInterval`, which will be the ID of the interval. Instead it should be returning a function that redux-saga can use to unsubscribe to events, as per the [docs](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#runsagaiterator-subscribe-dispatch-getstate-monitor). So your `subscribe` function should look more like this:

```
subscribe(callback) {
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => (callback({type: 'TEST'})), 1000);
  return () => { clearInterval(intervalId); };
},
```

Running it with this, I was able to see it loop through printing

```
1
2
3
4
{ type: 'TEST' }
```

It's weird how this caused your saga to become stuck, but I'm assuming that not receiving an `unsubscribe` function from `subscribe` caused things to become messed up internally in redux-saga.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed that. But notice that yelouafi [added on github](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/401#issuecomment-228019459) that returning clearInterval is not enough. "Subscribe function must support registering multiple subscriptions."

Comment: I think it would actually work because the intervalId for a specific subscription would be captured in the closure created by the unsubscribe function we build. So you could call subscribe multiple times and unsubscribe each of those individually with the function they return (since each function will be bound to the proper intervalId).